# The issue is that I have tokenized my data in a pandas data frame but I when I attempt to remove stop words, it does not remove the stop words

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
stop = stopwords.words('english')
lyrical_data['lyrics'] = lyrical_data.apply( lambda x : nltk.word_tokenize(str(x['lyrics'])), axis = 1)
lyrical_data['lyrics'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
```

Here I tokenize the column which works, however, when I execute the stop words it does excite but the output is not desired.

I expect the outcome to be something like this:
['i', 'like', 'to' play', 'drums']
-> ['like', 'play', 'drums]

But the output is still the same as the input. I would like to remove all the stop words stored in stop list in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to *re-assign* the column `lyrics` in the last line :

```
lyrical_data['lyrics'] = (
    lyrical_data['lyrics'].apply(
        lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
)
```

Output :

```
print(lyrical_data)

                lyrics
0  [like, play, drums]
```

Used input :

```
lyrical_data = pd.DataFrame({"lyrics": ["i like to play drums"]})
```

Note that you can replace both [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) calls with a single nested listcomp (*for efficiency*) :

```
lyrical_data["lyrics"] = [ # with optional " ".join()
    [w for w in word_tokenize(str(l)) if w.lower() not in stop]
        for l in lyrical_data["lyrics"]
]
```